# RecyclerView Adapter null after restoring Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-savedstate

I have a RecyclerView inside a fragment that is in a ViewPager. The problem is, when the view is restored, the RecyclerView is null and its adapter, which I need to update the contents, is also null.

How do I save the adapter state so that it isn't null when restoring the Fragment?

**Code**

```
//Inside fragment:
public override void OnResume()
{
        base.OnResume();

        (Activity as MainActivity).mLocation.ChangeFragments(this);
}
//Change Fragments calls this method:  
 private async void HomeLocation()
 {     
       JsonValue json;
        json = await GetZmanimAsync();

        (mFragment as HomeFragment).ParseAndDisplay(json);


            foreach (var time in (mFragment as HomeFragment).times)
            {
                time.GotTime = true;
            }

}

 public void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
    {

        if (times == null)
        {
            times = new List<TimeItem>();

            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "עלות השחר", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.alotIcon });
            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "זמן טו\"ת", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.tutIcon });

            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "נץ החמה", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.netzIcon });
            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "סו\"ז ק\"ש", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.shmaIcon });

            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "סו\"ז תפילה", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.DavenAnimation, isAnimation = true });
            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "זמן מנחה", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.DavenAnimation, isAnimation = true });

            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "שקיעה", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.shkiaaIcon });
            times.Add(new TimeItem() { TimeType = "צאת הכוכבים", ImageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.TzetIcon });
        }

        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[0] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//"עלות השחר 72 ד"]);
        times[0].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[2] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["זמן טלית ותפילין"]);
        times[1].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[3] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["זריחה"]);
        times[2].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[5] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["סוף זמן ק\"ש (גר\"א)"]);
        times[3].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[7] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["סוף זמן תפילה (גר\"א"]);
        times[4].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[9] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["מנחה גדולה"]);
        times[5].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[12] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["שקיעה"]);
        times[6].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");
        zman = DateTime.Parse((json[13] as JsonObject).Values.ToList()[1]);//DateTime.Parse(json["צאת הכוכבים"]);
        times[7].Time = zman.ToString("H:mm");


        mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: save the bundle in  ondestroy and restore on onResume or on createview

Comment: @quicklearner How do I save the bundle in ondestroy?

Comment: You can use this.setRetainInstance(true); in fragment

Comment: @androgo Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: save bundle in onDestroy

Comment: @quicklearner Could you please post some code as to how do I do this?

Comment: can u just what is the scenario ? like are u replacing the fragment with other  ? so i could post useful code for u

Comment: on tabchanged u want to retain the fragment state  or what ?

Comment: @quicklearner I'm not replacing the fragment. I have two fragments, each in a different tab. When I move to different apps, after some time, my app is destroyed, and when it tries to restore it, the adapter inside the fragment is null. Do you need more explanation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131671/discussion-between-quick-learner-and-amitairos).

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem? We need to know where and how your adapter is instantiated.